# VS2015 Large Seed method - CSC : error CS0041

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have developed an ASP.NET application using MVC, and everything has been going well, until I populated my Seed() method will the full dataset from the existing system that I am replacing (everything is fine with the cut down set I've been using for testing)

The Configuration.cs file is now approximately 2.5Mb and has around 4000 data elements being created in it.

With this large seed method I am getting the following error when I try and compile the application:

> CSC : error CS0041: Unexpected error writing debug information -- 'Insufficient memory to continue the execution of the program.'

I can't find any examples of people having run into this issue before, any help from anyone who has would be appreciated. Also note that although the error refers to debug information, this happens on a Release build as well.

Running Windows 7 x64 with 12Gb of memory, 6Gb free while the compiler is running ...

Answer (score 0):

Delete your project's `.PDB` file and try to compile again in `Release` mode. Else uninstall and re install Visual Studio. Deleting pdb files will mostly work.

Check [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/93sk305h(v=vs.90).aspx).

Comment: Unfortunately that error message seems to be misleading. If I comment out some of the data from the Seed() method everything works fine. As soon as I go past a certain amount of data the error occurs again. In the end I was able to solve this by disable pdb generation for release builds. It appears that the compiler is running out of memory while generating the pdb