# unexpected error writing debug information -- insufficient memory to continue to execution of the program

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I have developed an C#.Net console application using Telegram Bot API.

The ProcessUpdates.cs file is now approximately 2.11Mb and has around 30500 line of code.

I am getting the following error, when I trying build the project:

> unexpected error writing debug information -- insufficient memory to continue to execution of the program.

- I've found only one instance of this error in [This Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33409859/vs2015-large-seed-method-csc-error-cs0041http://), But I did not get any results of its response.
- Using Visual Studio 2015 Update-2 in Windows 10 x64 with 8Gb of memory.

Comment: 30k lines in one file?! Oh the code management should be fun :) So disabling .pdb generation in release build didn't helped?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the 'Release' Instead 'Debug' the problem is solved now, but I'm not sure again later cause problems or not.

Answer (score 0):

I had a 77k Lines program source within VS2017 which caused the same error.
The offending source was generated using a program that I wrote.

I solved the issue in splitting up a 50k lines C# method the source contained, by adding these 6 lines around a 23K lines code block within the method:

```
#if DEBUG              
     void myOffendingCodeBlock() {
#endif
    ... // the original code
#if DEBUG              
     } myOffendingCodeBlock();
#endif
```

Clearly, this will only work when there are no goto's that jump out of the code block.